# nova launch an instance failed ,error about libvirt

Tags: libvirt, openstack-nova

I use `virsh` (version 1.2.12) to create 1 controller node(hostname:HCP2-CTL-NODE-1),3 compute node(HCP2-CPT-NODE-1,2,3),the OS of these nodes is Centos7.
Then I follow [Openstack Newton Installation Doc for Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 and CentOS 7](https://docs.openstack.org/newton/install-guide-rdo/launch-instance.html) to deploy openstack on these 4 nodes.
However,when I want to launch an instance as the doc above show,it always return error state with the command

> openstack server show provider-instance0' return fault'Build of instance 3fcd26fb-da04-412b-9970-65901354292b aborted: Connection to the hypervisor is broken on host: HCP2-CPT-NODE-2'

Then I read the log

> /var/log/nova/nova-compute.log' on the host HCP2-CPT-NODE-2,

as followed:

```
<pre>

    2017-07-25 10:38:30.650 1010 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Attempting claim: memory 64 MB, disk 1 GB, vcpus 1 CPU
    2017-07-25 10:38:30.651 1010 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Total memory: 8191 MB, used: 512.00 MB
    2017-07-25 10:38:30.651 1010 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] memory limit: 12286.50 MB, free: 11774.50 MB
    2017-07-25 10:38:30.652 1010 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Total disk: 191 GB, used: 0.00 GB
    2017-07-25 10:38:30.652 1010 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] disk limit: 191.00 GB, free: 191.00 GB
    2017-07-25 10:38:30.653 1010 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Total vcpu: 4 VCPU, used: 0.00 VCPU
    2017-07-25 10:38:30.653 1010 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] vcpu limit not specified, defaulting to unlimited
    2017-07-25 10:38:30.655 1010 INFO nova.compute.claims [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Claim successful
    2017-07-25 10:38:30.980 1010 WARNING nova.scheduler.client.report [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Unable to refresh my resource provider record
    2017-07-25 10:38:32.088 1010 INFO nova.network.neutronv2.api [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Updating port 04aa7f73-eeb8-49b5-a8aa-f90a50ad4715 with attributes {'binding:host_id': u'HCP2-CPT-NODE-1'}
    2017-07-25 10:38:33.506 1010 WARNING nova.virt.osinfo [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Cannot find OS information - Reason: (No configuration information found for operating system Empty)
    2017-07-25 10:38:33.928 1010 WARNING nova.virt.osinfo [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Cannot find OS information - Reason: (No configuration information found for operating system Empty)
    2017-07-25 10:38:33.930 1010 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Creating image
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.227 1010 WARNING nova.virt.osinfo [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Cannot find OS information - Reason: (No configuration information found for operating system Empty)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.238 1010 INFO os_vif [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Successfully plugged vif VIFBridge(active=False,address=fa:16:3e:fa:22:ed,bridge_name='brq0ca57d3a-50',has_traffic_filtering=True,id=04aa7f73-eeb8-49b5-a8aa-f90a50ad4715,network=Network(0ca57d3a-50a6-446a-ab58-35aecbda0854),plugin='linux_bridge',port_profile=<?>,preserve_on_delete=False,vif_name='tap04aa7f73-ee')
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.718 1010 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-28838e00-d4b5-4378-ad64-7a31156d3ce6 - - - - -] Connection event '0' reason 'Connection to libvirt lost: 0'
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.723 1010 ERROR root [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Original exception being dropped: ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/guest.py", line 139, in launch\n    return self._domain.createWithFlags(flags)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 186, in doit\n    result = proxy_call(self._autowrap, f, *args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 144, in proxy_call\n    rv = execute(f, *args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 125, in execute\n    six.reraise(c, e, tb)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 83, in tworker\n    rv = meth(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1065, in createWithFlags\n    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError (\'virDomainCreateWithFlags() failed\', dom=self)\n', 'libvirtError: End of file while reading data: Input/output error\n']
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.724 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Failed to start libvirt guest
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.725 1010 INFO os_vif [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Successfully unplugged vif VIFBridge(active=False,address=fa:16:3e:fa:22:ed,bridge_name='brq0ca57d3a-50',has_traffic_filtering=True,id=04aa7f73-eeb8-49b5-a8aa-f90a50ad4715,network=Network(0ca57d3a-50a6-446a-ab58-35aecbda0854),plugin='linux_bridge',port_profile=<?>,preserve_on_delete=False,vif_name='tap04aa7f73-ee')
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.772 1010 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Deleting instance files /var/lib/nova/instances/8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436_del
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.773 1010 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Deletion of /var/lib/nova/instances/8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436_del complete
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.950 1010 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Connection event '0' reason 'Failed to connect to libvirt'
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Connection to libvirt failed: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 411, in get_connection
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     conn = self._get_connection()
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 398, in _get_connection
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     wrapped_conn = self._get_new_connection()
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 350, in _get_new_connection
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     wrapped_conn = self._connect(self._uri, self._read_only)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 204, in _connect
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     libvirt.openAuth, uri, auth, flags)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 144, in proxy_call
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     rv = execute(f, *args, **kwargs)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 125, in execute
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     six.reraise(c, e, tb)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 83, in tworker
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     rv = meth(*args, **kwargs)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 105, in openAuth
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.970 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host 
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR root [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Original exception being dropped: ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 4899, in _create_domain_and_network\n    post_xml_callback=post_xml_callback)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 4817, in _create_domain\n    guest.launch(pause=pause)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/guest.py", line 144, in launch\n    self._encoded_xml, errors=\'ignore\')\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/guest.py", line 111, in _encoded_xml\n    return encodeutils.safe_decode(self._domain.XMLDesc(0))\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 186, in doit\n    result = proxy_call(self._autowrap, f, *args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 144, in proxy_call\n    rv = execute(f, *args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 125, in execute\n    six.reraise(c, e, tb)\n', '  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 83, in tworker\n    rv = meth(*args, **kwargs)\n', '  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 492, in XMLDesc\n    if ret is None: raise libvirtError (\'virDomainGetXMLDesc() failed\', dom=self)\n', 'libvirtError: internal error: client socket is closed\n']
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Instance failed to spawn
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2083, in _build_resources
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     yield resources
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1924, in _build_and_run_instance
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     block_device_info=block_device_info)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 2618, in spawn
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     destroy_disks_on_failure=True)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 4927, in _create_domain_and_network
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     destroy_disks_on_failure)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 4849, in _cleanup_failed_start
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     destroy_disks=destroy_disks)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 977, in cleanup
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     self._undefine_domain(instance)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py", line 866, in _undefine_domain
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     guest = self._host.get_guest(instance)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 500, in get_guest
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     self.get_domain(instance))
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 490, in get_domain
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     return self._get_domain_by_name(instance.name)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 532, in _get_domain_by_name
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     conn = self.get_connection()
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 420, in get_connection
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     raise exception.HypervisorUnavailable(host=CONF.host)
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] HypervisorUnavailable: Connection to the hypervisor is broken on host: HCP2-CPT-NODE-1
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.973 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] 
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.975 1010 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Terminating instance
    2017-07-25 10:38:37.979 1010 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Connection event '0' reason 'Failed to connect to libvirt'
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Connection to libvirt failed: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 411, in get_connection
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     conn = self._get_connection()
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 398, in _get_connection
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     wrapped_conn = self._get_new_connection()
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 350, in _get_new_connection
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     wrapped_conn = self._connect(self._uri, self._read_only)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/host.py", line 204, in _connect
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     libvirt.openAuth, uri, auth, flags)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 144, in proxy_call
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     rv = execute(f, *args, **kwargs)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 125, in execute
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     six.reraise(c, e, tb)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/eventlet/tpool.py", line 83, in tworker
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     rv = meth(*args, **kwargs)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 105, in openAuth
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host     if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virConnectOpenAuth() failed')
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host libvirtError: Failed to connect socket to '/var/run/libvirt/libvirt-sock': Connection refused
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.000 1010 ERROR nova.virt.libvirt.host 
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.002 1010 WARNING nova.compute.manager [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Could not clean up failed build, not rescheduling. Error: Connection to the hypervisor is broken on host: HCP2-CPT-NODE-1
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.220 1010 WARNING nova.scheduler.client.report [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] Unable to refresh my resource provider record
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Build of instance 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436 aborted: Connection to the hypervisor is broken on host: HCP2-CPT-NODE-1
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Traceback (most recent call last):
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1783, in _do_build_and_run_instance
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     filter_properties)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1943, in _build_and_run_instance
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     'create.error', fault=e)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 220, in __exit__
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     self.force_reraise()
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/oslo_utils/excutils.py", line 196, in force_reraise
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     six.reraise(self.type_, self.value, self.tb)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 1927, in _build_and_run_instance
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     instance=instance)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py", line 2110, in _build_resources
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436]     reason=six.text_type(exc))
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] BuildAbortException: Build of instance 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436 aborted: Connection to the hypervisor is broken on host: HCP2-CPT-NODE-1
    2017-07-25 10:38:38.223 1010 ERROR nova.compute.manager [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] 
    2017-07-25 10:38:39.261 1010 INFO nova.compute.manager [req-37c22c56-598b-46f1-9e48-621b4c05fa23 57b1e00d821a450f8147033b4cf91544 c7ee1b57d11f4b5ca173381dbfa6fb90 - - -] [instance: 8d48b549-bd08-4e1f-8905-77e427036436] Took 1.04 seconds to deallocate network for instance.
    2017-07-25 10:39:01.040 1010 INFO nova.virt.libvirt.driver [req-285dc2e1-1716-4b98-b844-ee0ee120b34f - - - - -] Connection event '1' reason 'None'
    2017-07-25 10:39:01.133 1010 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-285dc2e1-1716-4b98-b844-ee0ee120b34f - - - - -] Auditing locally available compute resources for node HCP2-CPT-NODE-1
    2017-07-25 10:39:01.355 1010 WARNING nova.scheduler.client.report [req-285dc2e1-1716-4b98-b844-ee0ee120b34f - - - - -] No authentication information found for placement API. Placement is optional in Newton, but required in Ocata. Please enable the placement service before upgrading.
    2017-07-25 10:39:01.355 1010 WARNING nova.scheduler.client.report [req-285dc2e1-1716-4b98-b844-ee0ee120b34f - - - - -] Unable to refresh my resource provider record
    2017-07-25 10:39:01.625 1010 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-285dc2e1-1716-4b98-b844-ee0ee120b34f - - - - -] Total usable vcpus: 4, total allocated vcpus: 0
    2017-07-25 10:39:01.626 1010 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-285dc2e1-1716-4b98-b844-ee0ee120b34f - - - - -] Final resource view: name=HCP2-CPT-NODE-1 phys_ram=8191MB used_ram=512MB phys_disk=191GB used_disk=0GB total_vcpus=4 used_vcpus=0 pci_stats=[]
    2017-07-25 10:39:01.692 1010 WARNING nova.scheduler.client.report [req-285dc2e1-1716-4b98-b844-ee0ee120b34f - - - - -] Unable to refresh my resource provider record
    2017-07-25 10:39:01.692 1010 INFO nova.compute.resource_tracker [req-285dc2e1-1716-4b98-b844-ee0ee120b34f - - - - -] Compute_service record updated for HCP2-CPT-NODE-1:HCP2-CPT-NODE-1

</pre>
```

In addition,when i print the user groups on 3 compute node,it print:

```
<pre>
...
kvm:x:36:qemu
qemu:x:107:nova
cgred:x:993:
libvirt:x:992:
rpcuser:x:29:
nfsnobody:x:65534:
nova:x:162:
neutron:x:991:

</pre>
```

And the command "id nova" print :

```
<pre>
uid=162(nova) gid=162(nova) groups=162(nova),99(nobody),107(qemu)
</pre>
```

How to solve the problems? thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you run nova compute in vm, you should change "virt_type = qemu" in nova.conf.